# Net::Telnet output of cmd timed-out

Tags: perl, telnet

I tried to build a little telnet script to gain contact with the [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTelnet) module in Perl and I struggle with a command timeout when I try to receive the output.

```
$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10);
$telnet->errmode("return");
$telnet->open('192.168.0.187');
$telnet->waitfor('/Username: $/i');
$telnet->print('admin');
$telnet->waitfor('/Password: $/i');
$telnet->print('admin');
$telnet->waitfor('/admin  >$/i');
@output = $telnet->cmd('show');
#$telnet->waitfor('/admin  >$/i');
print @output;
```

But what I get is:

> command timed-out at telnet.pl line 12

Tried to increase the Timeout, set the errmode to return - but still getting that timeout.
Nevertheless the output of "show" on the server needs about 1 sec, so something else must be wrong I guess in my script ?

Answer (score 1):

Please tell us what line 12 in your script is. Your snippet above doesn't have a line 12.

This will help to identify whether it fails during the connect already or during a later command. Are you sure it's the "show" command which fails?

Comment: ya sorry my fault! yes it's the 'show' command. Every other one in the script is working. It's at least working if I don't catch output on the show-command.